# Nullpointer exception at ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

I do have an app which loads sounds from sdCard and shows it in AlertDialog as a `list`. It loads and plays sounds perfect. Now, I want to limit the amount of sounds to be loaded in the `list`. So, here is a task:

> I do have N sounds in folder at sdCard. I do have a list, where based
>   on condition I want to show A amount of sounds. The condition is: if
>   condition1>6 and condition2<40 then it's false and show 6 of sounds in
>   a list, otherwise if condition is true, show all sounds in a list.

Here is how I implemented it in a code, but it gives to me `NullPointerException`.

```
ins_mp3List = ins_Dir.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()); //list of all sounds in directory(N)

 user_instruments = new String[ins_mp3List.length]; //will be used in a system internally
 user_instruments_toShow =new String[ins_mp3List.length]; //will be shown in the list
 soundsQ_check=Integer.valueOf(custom_sounds.getString("RAW_1_1", ""));// the value is 0, it is checked
//Condition
 if (ins_mp3List.length>6 && soundsQ_check<40){ 
             user_instruments_block=true;
             for (int i=0; i<= 5; i++) {
              String [] seperated = ins_mp3List[i].toString().split(directory);
              user_instruments[i]=ins_mp3List[i].toString();
              user_instruments_toShow[i] = seperated[1];    
              Log.v("Instruments","true");
             }

         }else{
             for (int i=0; i< ins_mp3List.length; i++) {

              user_instruments_block=false;
              String [] seperated = ins_mp3List[i].toString().split(directory);
              user_instruments[i]=ins_mp3List[i].toString();
              user_instruments_toShow[i] = seperated[1];            
            Log.v("Instruments", user_instruments[i]);
               }
```

In the sdCard folder there are 8 files. `soundQ_check=0`.

LogCat gives error:

```
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2019)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:676)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:557)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:676)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:557)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2111)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-27 19:52:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(2667):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think that somewhere condition is wrong... Any help would be much appreciated. If, the amount of sounds less then 6 it works fine, but if it is more then 6 it gives nullPointerException...

UPD LAST: I've found a solution. I was not supposed to put

```
 user_instruments = new String[ins_mp3List.length]; //will be used in a system internally
 user_instruments_toShow =new String[ins_mp3List.length]; //will
```

outside the condition. These lines supposed to go under condition. Because of length varies it was giving to me error. Actual length was 8, and I was initializing only 6 of them. If to put that both strings under conditions it will work. Thanks for comments!

Comment: Please post code/line exactly where it shows NullPointerException, it would be better.

Comment: @PradeepSimha, nullPointer is at conditon

Comment: Please update same in question

Comment: @PradeepSimha, i have asked a question with all necessary information inside. If i would knew where exactly and why it gives nullPointer exception I wouldnt post it...

Comment: Looks like your `soundsQ_check` variable is `NULL`. Where do you initialise it? Or do you assign any value to it?

Comment: @Jens, I have initialized sounsQ_check it is 0.

Comment: What is the value of this ins_mp3List.length? try printing it

Comment: @PradeepSimha, it is the number of files in sdCard and it is 8

Comment: If you think the NPE occurs somewhere in this code, why do you not set a breakpoint at the beginning and step through it with the debugger? This will at least give you the exact line where the NPE happens. I don't understand how your code has something to do with an ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that it works fine if it is less than 6. It is because you have used && operator in your condition and if first condition becomes false it doesn't check for second condition and hence not access `soundQ_check`.What I think this line is affecting you variable:

```
 soundsQ_check=Integer.valueOf(custom_sounds.getString("RAW_1_1", ""));
```

you can debug it by printing value of this variable after this line.

Comment: the value of soundsQ_check is 0. I have printed it. I knew i sued `&&` because only if both of them are true then i want to take one action if it s not, other action